# How to trigger Apache camel route from my java method

Tags: apache, routes, apache-camel

I am new to Apache Camel.

My requirement is to trigger an Apache camel route in my code flow from method A(). Also I need to pass the object param of A() to the route. I do not want to use amq, file etc components.

code :

```
public void A(MyObjectType param) {
    //Need to call camel route with "param"
}
```

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: What do you want to do with the route? How is that parameter going to be used?

Comment: The route will do filtering for a particular use case based on input param object passed and further pass the flow to downstream code. For ex :- The route will check 
if { inputObjectParam.Customer.Location == 'US' } 
then route it to Route A 
else
Route it to Route B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ProducerTemplate option, ProducerTemplate template = exchange.getContext().createProducerTemplate() and then you can do template.sendBody 
The sendBody method can invoke a camel route directly.