# Is it possible to call a Camel Route xml from Java method?

Tags: java, apache-camel, spring-camel

I am trying to call a camel route xml from the Java method. Is it possible to call and return to the same method again?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to trigger Apache camel route from my java method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25911995/how-to-trigger-apache-camel-route-from-my-java-method)

Comment: I have answered a similar question before. Hope this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61429011/5891534

Comment: Yes you can have both Java and XML routes in the same CamelContext and they are at runtime "the same" from Camel point of view. So you can just call the routes via direct/seda endpoints etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a [ProducerTemplate](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/producertemplate.html) for that.

If your caller has to wait for the route to complete, your route must be executed synchronously (for example [`direct` routes](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/direct-component.html)). See [exchange pattern](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/exchange-pattern.html) for more details.

If you expect a response from the route you should use one of the [`request*` methods](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/producertemplate.html#ProducerTemplate-requestmethods) of the producer template (not the `send*` methods).